# How to use custom code activity in sharepoint online workflow?

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow

We have developed one **declarative workflow & custom code activity**. We are calling this code activity from declarative workflow. This workflow is deployed on sharepoint server 2013 & its working fine. But we want to use same workflow on **sharepoint online** site.

I know we cant deploy custom code activity on sharepoint online.

So how can we use this activity in SPOnline? Can we deploy it on Azure and call from workflow? If Yes then can anyone give me detailed information on it. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are building complex workflows which can't be developed using SPD then your only option is to create an [APP](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/create-a-sharepoint-workflow-app-using-visual-studio-2012).

In online visual studio workflows you loose the ability of using code behind. You should use RESTFUL services which returns data in JSON format.

For more information read http://satalyst.com/creating-list-workflow-sharepoint-online-2013-using-visual-studio/

Here is an msdn article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163199(v=office.15).aspx#bkm_Debug